# CONCAT returns wrong data

Tags: mysql

I am using `CONCAT('€ ', FORMAT(t_plus, 2))` statement to get data from my database. But this statement returns always a value. Even if the row is empty the SQL returns `€ 0.00`.

I dont want to show the empty rows as `€ 0.00`.

Does someone know how I can fix this?

Here is the full sql statement:

```
SELECT date_format(date, '%e %M %Y') AS date, 
       CONCAT('€ ', FORMAT(t_plus, 2)) as t_plus, 
       CONCAT('€ ', FORMAT(t_min, 2)) as t_min
FROM trans
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `IF` to handle empty values, e.g.:

```
SELECT date_format(date, '%e %M %Y') AS date, 
   IF(t_plus != '', CONCAT('€ ', FORMAT(t_plus, 2)), '') as t_plus, 
   IF(t_min != '', CONCAT('€ ', FORMAT(t_min, 2)), '') as t_min
FROM trans
```

Comment: This will not work for me. If `t_plus` contains data `t_min` is empty. If `t_min` contains data `t_plus` is empty. With this statement the data in the `t_min`  column gets ignored

Comment: @John so what is the expected output of the value is null? Just an empty cell?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CASE` expression like

```
case when t_plus is not null then CONCAT('€ ', FORMAT(t_plus, 2)) 
else null end as t_plus
```

Comment: It didnt change anything. I still get € 0.00

Comment: I changed the data in my database. The empty rows are now NULL. The statement shows now `null` instead of `€ 0.00`

Comment: @John, yes that's what expected ... if you want to discard the entire row then you should check the other answer provided

Comment: The other anwer wont work for me. If `t_plus` contains data `t_min` is empty. If `t_min` contains data `t_plus` is empty. With this statement the data in the `t_min`  column gets ignored